# How do I implement "fog of war" effect for 2D maze using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a 2 dimensional maze that I draw onto a canvas. A red dot on the maze is displayed to show the user their position in the maze as they navigate their way around. Currently the entire maze is visible which poses a problem.

I would like to make it such that:

1. only a portion of the maze where the user is can be clearly visible,
2. previous portions of the maze that the user visited are visible, but "greyed out".
3. there are other entities roaming the maze, they should only be visible within the portion of the maze that is completely visible, in other words, from within a few cells of the current position of the user; though visited hallways remain partially visible, any entities roaming those portions of the maze are not visible.

I've been looking into using the OpacityMask property for this, which is likely easy to implement for the visible portion of the user present location, but then how do I implement leaving the visited areas "greyed"?

Comment: Disagree with 'too broad', this is a straightforward design issue - it's not a huge project, just a piece of a system, and OP is looking for implementation ideas.

Comment: Traditionally this would be done with a 2D bitmap where each bit representing a 1" region or something. You might be able to do this if you're using shader effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use two `OpacityMask` layers over the top of your entire maze.

The first describes "where you are", which defines what you can currently see clearly, and everything else will be 50% opaque or 'grey'.

The second describes where you've been, transparent where you've been and everything else black. The transparent "where you've been" area will allow the user to see through to the underneath "where you are" layer, to show the grey/transparent areas of where you are and were you are not.

Each layer has some complexity.

- The first has a trivial shape (just a circle about the location of the user) but needs to disallow the underlying objects from refreshing; i.e. something in the grey area should not refresh or redraw.
- The second has a trivial redraw (you can't see under the black anyway), but the shape will be much more complex. It can probably be a union of all the "where you are" circles, sampled every few seconds, if that's feasible.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I expected I would need to do, just wasn't aware it was allowed. So, that second layer is what I've been struggling with most.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is far too general but I'll do my best to get you moving in the right direction.

So, firstly each cell should be an object. It needs some properties like;

```
    int x // x coordinate
    int y // y coordinate
    bool isVisible // marks if the cell is currently in full view
    bool beenSeen // marks if the user has been here
```

Each time the user moves you should call some method like `RefreshMap(Cell Current);`

In this method you should find all the bordering cells (using the x, and y values) and mark them as visible. You should also mark the current cell as `beenSeen`. The refresh map should probably change the data, then some other method should re render the map with the current data.

This is a very rough idea of how you implement this type of thing. Don't take it too seriously. It should suffice for your current project, I'm sure what's used in a real games is far more sophisticated.